# Problems while restoring application from backup

Tags: android, installation, backup, launcher

I have a rooted android phone, I am working on an app which does backup of application installed in sdcard to PC. I am able to successfully backup the application from sdcard to PC. While restoring the application from the backup, I restored all files(asec,pkg,cache,data) pertaining to the application in the exact same place they were, including the permissions. When i reboot or restart the launcher the application does not show up as installed. Instead asec or pkg are getting flushed after (reboot)/(restart of launcher).

What should be done to make the application show up as installed after restoring?

Comment: Don't you have to *install* it?  Through the system install functionality.  That said, we don't handle dev questions -- migrating to [SO].

Comment: Why should it be done via system install functionality, if i am able restore all the changes done by an application while installing?

Comment: And why would you code all of that when the system already has the functionality?

Comment: How to use that system install functionality(via code)?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, using **pm** helped the cause.